# Is it possible to check specific values with eCATT?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, sap-erp, sap-basis

I'm researching for [eCATT](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECATT) and found a lot of examples, but I found no example for my question.

With eCATT I can check transactions with different test data. But I found no example if it is possible to check specific data.

It is possible to *Test updates (database, applications, GUI)* (see [abap-tutorials.com](http://www.abap-tutorials.com/2010/11/10/belling-the-ecatt-extended-computer-aided-test-tool/)), but can I also check the result of some fields?

Example: I check VA01 with different customers and materials. I can check, if VA01 works fine and an order is created. But is it possible to check, if the net value of the order (VBAK-NETWR) is the same as my expected price?

---

Update:
I found another [book at sappress](http://www.sap-press.de/katalog/buecher/htmlleseproben/gp/htmlprobID-55). 
At the end of the section *Commands* is the following text:

> In individual cases, however, it can be necessary to directly search a database table for the existence and characteristics of specific values.

This sounds like a positive answer for my question, but I would like to get a confirmation and perhaps an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [description for the scenario](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/49/70aa6b81463e90e10000000a42189c/content.htm) I'm looking for

> Parameterize the CheckAction and ExpectedValue fields as required. You also have the option of parameterizing the Value field to perform a GET

In the book "[SAP Lösungen testen](http://www.sap-press.de/download/dateien/1107/sappress_sap_loesungen_testen.pdf)" (sorry, German) is a description of the feature I'm looking for. See page 207 (in pdf-extract page 42). (*GETGUI/CHEGUI*)